# How can i write many "OR" in one "IF" javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i write many "OR" in one "IF" javascript? This code is wrong:

```
if (d.getMinutes().toString() == 1 || 21 || 31 || 41 || 51){
  Something happen
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your problem to something like this

Store the values you want to compare in `array` and pass into [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)() the original value to achieve that.

```
if ([1,21,31,41,51].includes(d.getMinutes())){
  Something happen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, each individual condition must evaluate to a boolean.

```
var dMinutes = d.getMinutes().toString();
if (dMinutes == 1 || dMinutes == 21 || dMinutes == 31 || dMinutes == 41 || dMinutes == 51){
  Something happen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat `d.getMinutes().toString()` in your `if`, it's common approach to use an array and `includes()` for that purpose:

```js
if ([1, 21, 31, 41, 51].includes(d.getMinutes()) {
```

Note that `toString()` is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dMinutes = d.getMinutes().toString();
if ( dMinutes == 1 || dMinutes == 21 || dMinutes == 31 || dMinutes == 41 || dMinutes == 51 ) {
  Something happen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if ([1, 21, 31, 41, 51].indexOf(d.getMinutes()) !== -1){
 Something happen
}
```

The toString would not help because the array are numbers

There might be better solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same with cleaner code (you don't need `toString` here):

```js
var d = new Date(2010, 1, 1, 10, 21, 0);
if ([1, 21, 31, 41, 51].includes(d.getMinutes())) {
  // do something
  console.log("21 minutes");
}

var d2 = new Date(2010, 1, 1, 10, 25, 0);
if ([1, 21, 31, 41, 51].includes(d2.getMinutes())) {
  // do something
  console.log("This is not executed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I did for a project that you might find useful. This applies with user input, but I'm also sure it could be transformed to match what it is you're doing! try using "else if" instead of "or" for multiple options.

```js
function yourFunction(str) {
   len = str.length;
   mod = len % 4;
   if (mod === 0) {
     return "Option 1"
   }
   else if (mod === 1) {
     return "Option 2"
   }
   else if (mod === 2) {
     return "Option 3"
   }
   else if (mod === 3) {
     return "Option 4"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you could simply the [modulo operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp):

```
if (d.getMinutes() % 10 == 1){
  // Something happens
}
```

since every minute value that you listed ends with `1`, and you listed all the possible values ending with `1`.